# What is $W_2^{1,1/2}(Q_T)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

In the book "linear and quasi-linear equations of parabolic type", it defines the space $W_q^{2l,l}(Q_T)$. But what is $W_2^{1,1/2}(Q_T)$. Is it the special case when $l=1/2$?

[image]

Comment: The spaces $W_q^{l,l/2}(Q_T)$ will be defined in §3 of Chapter II, as it says at the bottom of your picture.

Comment: @stange but is l not a integer in chapter II